# Mocha test log to save to a separate file

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I need to store my mocha test result to a different file as well.

am trying to run

`mocha -R spec  test/**/*_test.js > report 2>&1`

on my terminal but it shows

`'mocha' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Where am i going wrong?

ps i have already run `npm install mocha -g`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all run this command to test mocha is globally installed or not.

which mocha

Comment: yeah, mocha is globally installed, still not working.